# Splitting Field of $(x^3-2)(x^2-2)$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and its degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I would like to find the splitting field of the polynomial $f=(X^3-2)(X^2-2)\in\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ and then calculate its degree over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

I can rewrite this polynomial into $(X^3-2)(X^2-2)=(X^3+1)(X^2-2)=(X+1)^3(X^2-2)$ (since we can apply to Frobenius for $p=3$). Then it seems that $f$ is not irreducible and even already has a root in $2\in\mathbb{F}_3$! Now what comes up in my mind are:

1) The field $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/\langle(X^2-2)\rangle$

2) The field $\mathbb{F}_3[\sqrt2]$

but somehow I feel that both of them are not the correct answer. Once I know what the splitting field looks like then maybe I will have a better idea on what its degree is.

I've already seen a couple of questions which seems relevant, but still can't find a general idea to solve this kind of question. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: The options 1) and 2) are isomorphic. How does $f$ factor in them?

Comment: @Thorgott I'm not sure... do you mean how $f$ factorise in this field?

Comment: Yes. The two fields you suggest are isomorphic. And both splitting fields for this polynomial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But I can't find a linear factorization of $f$ in this field (even though if I find them then it's done). I suppose I should first split $f$ into a form like $(X-a)g(X)$ where $g$ is quadratic and irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: The factorization is surely $(X+1)^3(X-\sqrt2)(X+\sqrt2)$, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. But in this way we have a triple root (namely 2)...

Comment: Why would that be a problem? Some polynomials have triple roots.

Comment: Indeed, the construction of the splitting field usually begins by creating an extension field by using an irreducible factor to get (at least) one zero. But: A) You cannot use $X^3-2$ to that end for it is not irreducible. B) Even then it may happen that you get a root with higher multiplicity.

Comment: Oh I guess I mixed it up with the definition of seperable polynomials... so we have the roots $\{2,2,2,\sqrt2,\sqrt{-2}\}$ and further the degree of the splitting field is $2$ since $(\sqrt2)^2=2\in\mathbb{F}_3$, right?

Comment: Correct. Well done.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me so much!